# Cloud Spanner alert based on a select query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I have a query which I run daily on our database in gcp cloud. The query outputs a count and if the count is greater than zero we have to perform a certain task.

What I am looking for is that how can I generate a email when the count is greater than zero so that I don't have to login to GCP every time. What would be the best approach for the same.

Can I connect to the cloud spanner db from my laptop or do I have to login to GCP every time?

Please help, I am new to GCP.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you write a small application that executes the query for you, and then create a [Cloud Run Job](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/execute/jobs) that is [scheduled](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/execute/jobs-on-schedule) to run once every 24 hours.

You don't write which programming language(s) you are comfortable with, but there are multiple [getting started guides](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/getting-started/java) for Cloud Spanner in various languages.

Getting started guides for Cloud Run Jobs can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts#build-and-create-a-job

---

If your database is a PostgreSQL-dialect Cloud Spanner database, then there are examples for how you can use a standard PostgreSQL driver with Cloud Spanner in combination with PGAdapter on Cloud Run here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pgadapter/tree/postgresql-dialect/samples/cloud-run